# How to achieve Always retry policy/Custom Retry Policy for a Kafka Consumer without causing a rebalance in the group

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I am trying to write a resilient Kafka consumer. If there occurs an exception while processing the message in the listener method, I would like to retry it. I would like to retry a few times for certain exceptions, always for certain exceptions and never for the rest. I have read the Spring docs regarding SeekToCurrentErrorHandler, but not 100% sure how to implement it.

I have subclassed the ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy and and am returning the appropriate Retry Policy based on the exceptions that occur in the Listener method.

I have created RetryTemplate and have and set its RetryPolicy with my custom implementation in the subclass.

I have set the retryTemplate on the Kafka container. I have set the error handler to be new SeekToCurrentHandler and also set the stateful retry property to be true.

Listener Method

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", containerFactory = "containerFactory")
   public void listenToKafkaTopic(@Payload Message<SomeAvroGeneratedClass> message, Acknowledgement ack){
      SomeAvroGeneratedClass obj = message.getPayLoad();
      processIncomingMessage(obj);
      ack.acknowledge();
   }
```

Custom Retry Policy class

```
 @Component
 public class MyRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy
   {
      @PostConstruct
       public void init(){
             final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
             simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(8);

     this.setExceptionClassifier( classifiable ->
           {
        // Always Retry when instanceOf   TransientDataAccessException
       if( classifiable.getCause() instanceof TransientDataAccessException)
            {
               return new AlwaysRetryPolicy();                                         

            }
      else if(classifiable.getCause() instanceOf NonTransientDataAccessException)
           {
              return new NeverRetryPolicy();
           }
          else
            {
            return simpleRetryPolicy;
            }

      } );
 }}
```

Retry Template and Container Config

```
@Configuration
public class RetryConfig{


 @Bean
 public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(@Autowired ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory){

   RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
   retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new MyRetryPolicy());
   FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy()
   fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
   retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

   factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
   factory.setAckOnError(false);
   factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
   factory.setStateFulRetry(true);
   factory.setRecoveryCallback(//configure recovery after retries are exhausted and commit offset
   );

  }
}
```

Listener properties:

1. AckMode = Manual
2. auto.offset.commit = false

Question:

1. With my current code, can I achieve my retry logic defined in MyRetryPolicy without causing a consumer rebalance when AlwaysRetryPolicy is returned? If no, please direct me in the right path.
2. Is my approach right in using the Error handler as well as the Retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stateful retry in conjunction with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` is the right approach.

However, if you are using a recent version (2.2 or higher), the error handler will give up after 10 attempts; you can make that infinity with by setting `maxFailures` to -1 (2.2) or the `backOff` with `Long.MAX_VALUE` (2.3 or higher).

Comment: Okay. But what if my retry policy evaluates to a simple retry policy based on the exception occurred which would retry for a finite no of times as defined in MyRetryPolicy class, does setting the maxFailures to -1 or backOff with Long.MAX_VALUE on the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler override the retry policy returned? I mean would it retry infinitely? If so, this is not the behaviour I expect. I would like to retry finitely for certain exceptions and infinitely for other set of exceptions and never for the rest all while not causing a consumer group rebalance.

Comment: When using stateful recovery, the recovery **must be done in the listener's retry recovery callback**, not the STCEH - otherwise you will have a memory leak (the state in the retry template). i.e. the `recoveryCallback` should return normally after retries are exhausted for a retryable exception. The STCEH is not invoked when the listener exits normally so the `maxAttempts` setting does not apply.

Comment: When you say " the recovery must be done in the listener's retry recovery callback" is it setting the recovery callback on the container factory? For ex: factory.setRecoveryCallback(//commit offset after retires are exhausted
   ); ? Is my understanding right regarding your comment?

Comment: Yes; that is correct; when retries are exhausted, the callback is called and you do something (log, send to DLQ topic, etc). If that exits normally, we won't re-seek the record.

Comment: Just realized that we cannot move past 2.1.12 version of spring-Kafka. In 2.1.12, there's no constructor's that would take in maxInterval or backOff. There's  only the default constructor. Is there any different approach do I need to take for version's below 2.2 or just setting the error handler of the container factory to new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler should do the trick?

Comment: The 2.1 version of `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` always retries so everything will work as you expected.

Comment: In spring-kaka version 2.4.0 RELEASE, is this how we achieve infinite retries?
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(4000l, Long.MAX_VALUE)));
As suggested in the answer, the backoff is implemented using FixedBackOff with an interval of 4 seconds and maxAttempts is set to Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Yes, but the current spring-kafka 2.4.x version is 2.4.12. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn I would not recommend using 2.4.0.

Comment: Okay. Will check the version suggested. By configuring the below on the listener container factory

factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(4000l, Long.MAX_VALUE)));

will my Custom Retry Policy still work or would it get overridden by the abv setting ?

I am trying to achieve infinite retries only for a certain kind of exception that occurs during runtime and for others it should exit after the retries are exhausted. Please refer to the MyRetryPolicy class in the Question.

Comment: No; you need to upgrade to 2.6.x to provide a different back off, based on exception type `public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction)`

Comment: Okay. When you said "No", I've understood that my custom retry policy would not work with 2.4.0 RELEASE while using a backoff that retries infinitely. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any way to achieve different retry policies based on exception occurred using 2.4.x?

Comment: Sorry if its confusing, but all I am trying to achieve is retry a couple of times for a certain exception and retry infinitely for another exception using 2.4.x. Any example would greatly help. Also, thanks for your quick and prompt responses

Comment: No; with versions prior to 2.6, you have to use stateful retry for that functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227173/discussion-between-rohit-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to replace the retry template (which you can do in 2.6.x). Yes, if you still have the template, with infinite retries in the error handler, it will do what you want. You just need to make sure the aggregate back-offs in the template do not exceed `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: are aggregate backoffs = no of retries ? If yes, when an exception occurs and it has to be retried for a finite number of times, the total time taken for the message processing including the retries should not exceed max.poll.interval.ms. Is that what you meant when you said "ggregate back-offs in the template do not exceed max.poll.interval.ms"?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-spoke; it's aggregate back-offs (sum of back-off intervals) when NOT using stateful retry; with stateful retry, it's the max back off that must be less than the poll interval.

Comment: factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(4000l, Long.MAX_VALUE))); 

In the above line of code, the FixedBackOff is constructed by passing in 4000l, which evaluates to 4 seconds as interval and Long.MAX_VALUE as maxAttempts. Can I safely assume 4 seconds as the max back off between each retry which is less than the default poll interval? I will be using stateful retry

Comment: Since you also have a back off in the retry template, it will be the sum of the two; it's best to define the back off in just one place and set the other to zero.

Comment: Understood. i will remove the back off policy that is set on the retry template and use the back off that's configured on the error handler. Again, thanks for all your guidance.